# What is wrong with these filenames?

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, filenames

I can't seem to get my filenames in a format that is recognizable. I originally had them in ANSI format and tried to convert them to UTF-8, but they are still not recognizable.

The filenames are in Japanese. Any ideas? I already have a Japanese language pack installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! I figured it out. I should have used the following:

> convmv --notest -f SHIFT_JIS -t UTF-8 *